# Why does this video element have the wrong aspect ratio before playback?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I embed a video with a resolution of 768x576 pixels. That's an aspect ratio of 4/3.

But although I specify the correct `width` and `height` in HTML and set both of them to `100%` in CSS, the browser infers an aspect ratio of 2/1.

It only corrects the aspect ratio once I start playback. Why is that?

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 44em;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Video aspect ratio problem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <figure>
      <video
        src="https://ia800303.us.archive.org/6/items/coughs_and_sneezes_TNA/coughs_and_sneezes_TNA_512kb.mp4"
        width="768"
        height="576"
        preload="none"
        controls
      ></video>
    </figure>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your video tag with video not preloaded doesn't have any size. In your css if you put video width 768px and height 576px, it's working

Comment: @pier farrugia Yes. But then responsive layout is broken. I'd prefer a solution that keeps the other properties of the document intact.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know that. Could you put a preload image in your video? Image from the clip, not obliged the first one, one which represent the movie. This way your video tag would be dimensioned by the image even if not video by itself not yet loaded.

Comment: That’s a reasonable and pragmatic suggestion. However, I’d still like to understand why the video player is in the wrong aspect ratio in the first place.

Comment: I made some search, seems that default video player size (if nothing in yet) is 300x150, meaning aspect ratio 2/1. Your video is 4/3. Could you make parent container with a ratio of 4/3, and put the video in 100% 100%?